# Java Generic getting type parameter

Tags: java, scala, generics, higher-kinded-types

In Scala, you can define a class as this:

```
class MyClass[T1[T2]] {
  def abc(a1: T1[Double]):T1[Int] = ???
}
```

In this code, type parameter `T1` represents a type that needs one type parameter `T2`, so we can create an instance like `new MyClass[List]`.

I want to do this in Java, but I don't have any idea.

I wonder if it is possible in Java, and if not, any idea how I can do this thing in Java.

From my understanding, generic type essentially makes a function of types. So if you have a class like `List<T>`, you can think of the class `List` a function of type, so `List` takes a type parameter like `Integer`, then it will be a concrete type like list of integers(`List<Integer>`).

`MyClass` above takes a type parameter `T1`, but I want this `T1` is also a generic type that takes a type parameter `T2`, so I can create an instance like `MyClass<List>` and can use type like `List<Integer>` or `List<Double>` inside `MyClass`. In Scala, if you try `MyClass[Int]` or `MyClass[String]` will fail because `Int` or `String` does not take a type parameter.

Of course, this may not be necessary if I allow to duplicate some codes, but to make a more general code, I think it is indispensable.

Comment: @dimo414 You are wrong. What he means is: can he do `class MyClass<T1<T2>>` and in method return `T1<Integer>`? How do you specify at compile time that `T1` is a polymorphic type.

Comment: @Jatin what, exactly, am I wrong about?  I made a factual statement that Java uses angle brackets for generics, and provided a resource to learn more.  I did not attempt to answer the question, which is why I posted a *comment* and not an *answer*.

Comment: @dimo414 the code in the question is a Scala code, and Scala uses square bracket. Sorry for misleading. @Jatin is right. I want to know if it is possible to define a class like `class MyClass<T1<T2>>`.

Comment: @dimo414 From your comment `Java uses angle brackets for generic types` implies you are trying to say just replace `[]` with `<>`. Everyone knows it. And providing a general reference to `generics tutorial` is like providing a link to wikipedia page. **How does it help?**

Comment: And no, `class MyClass<T1<T2>>` does not compile in java as by default compiler only considers one level in generic type. I think it is an excellent question

Comment: Ah, I see that now, my apologies, I didn't fully understand the question.

Comment: @JJS - could you expand your question, particularly what you're hoping to accomplish?  I'm inclined to think what you're describing is not possible in Java, but if you can expand on what you're trying to do, there may well be an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way for this to work in Java is to have a common interface for `T1`.

```
public interface GenericType<T> {
    // ...
}
```

Then you can define your class as:

```
class MyClass {
    public GenericType<Integer> abc(GenericType<Double> a1) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need any more type parameters at the class level anymore because of the common interface. Then before invoking `MyClass.abc` you would need to wrap the instance you are passing in `GenericType`.

You can also go one abstraction level higher and define

```
class MyClass<T1,T2> {
    public GenericType<T1> abc(GenericType<T2> a1) {
        //...
    }
}
```

This would give you some more flexibility in using `MyClass`. But that is heavily dependent upon how `MyClass` is actually implemented.